# EF Core 5: Include With Where Statement Followed by ThenInclude -- Inheritance Problem

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a project that I'm developing.  First, the schema is pretty simple; I have a user, and the user works at many warehouses.  There are different types of warehouses, but -- for this example -- I'll keep it simple.  In this example, we have a ManagedWarehouse that inherits from Warehouse.

Here are the classes:

```
public class User
{
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
     public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class ManagedWarehouse : Warehouse
{
     public int GeneralManagerId { get; set; }
     public User GeneralManager { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm creating a EF query that will allow me to get all users along with the ACTIVE warehouses they work.  Additionally, if the warehouse is a `ManagedWarehouse`, the GeneralManager will be returned as well.

Here's my query:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
     return this.DbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Warehouses.Where(wh => wh.IsActive)).ThenInclude(wh => ((ManagedWarehouse)wh).GeneralManager);
}
```

This seems like a simple query, but it won't compile.  It's complaining that the call is ambiguous:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable>, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>>)' and 'EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty>, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>>)'

If I REMOVE the `.Where(wh => wh.IsActive)`, it will compile, but -- again -- I only want the warehouses that are active to be returned.  How can I make this "unambiguous" while still returning the data that I need?  Thank you.

Comment: `Select` is not an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF Core `ThenInclude` pattern has issues with C# IntelliSense/compiler from the beginning due to the way two overloads are defined - one for `T` and one for `IEnumerable<T>`. Since both overloads are applicable, looks like the compiler can infer the correct overload only when you use some direct property/method of `T`, otherwise (any other operator on the argument, including cast, `as` etc. as in the question) it fails.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```cs
class A
{
    public IEnumerable<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public C C { get; set; }
}

class C
{
}

static void Test(IQueryable<A> source)
{
    var includable = source
        .Include(a => a.Bs);
    var compiles = includable.ThenInclude(b => b.C);
    var doesNotCompile = includable.ThenInclude(b => ((B)b).C); // CS0121
}
```

The cast is redundant, since `b` type is `B`, but it breaks the compiler. Interestingly, this happens only when the previous expression return the exact interface (`IEnumerable<T>` in this case) - if the expression is derived class/interface (in this case, `IReadOnlyCollection<T`, `List<T>` etc.), the compiler inference works.

And this is the reason `ThenInclude` to fail on filtered `Include`, since it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, even though it would happen also with regular `Include` if the collection navigation property type is `IEnumerable<T>` (supported by EF Core) rather than the usual `ICollection<T>` or other derived type.

With that being said, I'm not sure whether this should be treated (and reported) as EF Core API design bug or C# compiler issue. But in either case I don't think it would be fixed soon. So as a workaround, let compiler recognize the desired overload by explicitly specifying the argument type:

```cs
.ThenInclude((Warehouse wh) => ((ManagedWarehouse)wh).GeneralManager)
//               ^^^
```